# Backup Windows 7 recovery drive onto DVD

Tags: windows-7, system-repair-disc

I have laptop which runs Windows 7. There is an OS recovery drive on it. I don't know how to backup that software onto a DVD. How can I do that?

Comment: What does this have to do with Google Chrome?

Comment: Theres usually an OEM specific software for it - what brand?

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of backup software on the internet but windows 7 has its own restore disc generator.

Here is a support page for Windows 7. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/create-a-system-repair-disc